# jQueryでファイルを送信する方法について

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

html

```
<textarea id="blogContentInputArea" class="form-control"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="送信" onclick="blogContribution();" class="submitButton"/>
```

javascript

```
function blogContribution()
{
    var content = $("#blogContentInputArea").val();
    $.post(`/blog/blogAdds`,{ content: content },
    (data) => {

    });
}
```

上記のように、テキストエリアと、送信ボタンの2つがあるhtmlを作成し
javascriptファイルを読み込んで、jQueryでテキストエリアの内容をpostで送ろうと思っています。

htmlに1行追加して、ファイル選択画面を付け、
テキストエリアの内容の送信と、ファイルの送信を同時に行いたいのですが
どうすれば出来ますか？

```
<textarea id="blogContentInputArea" class="form-control"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="upfile" value="" class="fileuploader"/>
<input type="button" value="送信" onclick="blogContribution();" class="submitButton"/>
```

サーバ側では、Node.js + Expressを使用しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もし、ajaxで`multipart/form-data`で送信したいという意味であれば `FormData` を利用して送信することが可能です。

```js
$(document.forms.someForm).submit(function(){
  $.ajax('/blog/blogAdds', {
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData(this),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false, 
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="someForm">
  <textarea id="blogContentInputArea" class="form-control"></textarea>
  <input type="file" name="upfile" value="" class="fileuploader"/>
  <input type="submit" value="送信" class="submitButton"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

form要素でラップしてsubmitする方法ではいかがでしょうか？
enctype属性の指定をしてあげればアップロードできます。

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="frm">
```